# How to convert year into unixtimestamp?

Tags: php, mysql

I have Mysql database with around 800 entries.

I have only year in field **recordingdate** field without month and day. For example ***2015***.

I want to convert such year in Unix Time Stamp. With year alone we cannot conver into Unix time stamp unless I give proper date format. I want to edit each field something like this ***2015-01-01***. I can atleast give month ***1*** and day ***1***.

The problem is I have more than 800 rows. How can I achieve this without editing each row one by one?

Any Mysql or PHP solutions can work.

Comment: what did you tried so far? please edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to update the field to desired format.

```
UPDATE TABLE SET recordingdate = CONCAT(recordingdate, "-01-01")
```

Then you can use UNIX_TIMESTAMP() or you can of course combine them

```
UPDATE TABLE SET recordingdate_ts = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(recordingdate, "-01-01"))
```